# Resolving conflicts during git rebase

Tags: git, rebase

For the sake of simplicity, imagine following case:

```
      D---E---F--- ... ---Z  topic
     /
A---B---C                    master
```

I'd like to rebase on master, so that the `D` to `Z` "chain" is after `C`, however, all the `D`, `E`, `F`, ..., `Z` commits creates a conflicts when rebasing them 1 by 1. Let's just say that each of them has a conflict on a different line with commit `C`.

I'd like to resolve all those conflict at once and not in the rebase interactive mode (`--continue, --abort, --skip`), or what ever it is. My question is whether it's totally bad to ignore the conflicts and do the conflict resolution at the very end. By a new explicit commit or in the last rebase step.

By ingoring I mean: `git add -A && git commit`

This will lead to the history where some commits contain the code-base in the state that's not working, right?

ps. I don't wan't to be merging, I'd like to rebase.

Comment: God no - this means that your master branch will have _non compiling commits_ - a terrible idea (not to speak of other git commands like rerere being completelly borged)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is a bad idea to ignore conflicts reported by Git. The logical change from `C` to `D` is not likely to be achieved by the same code change between `B` and `D`. If it were simple enough, then Git would not have asked for intervention. If you don't care about history, you could combine all the `D` to `Z` commits into one and then try to rebase.

Comment: Right, squashing D to Z into 1 big commit seems to be the best. thx

Answer (score 0):

You have the `git rerere` command for your help.

#### [`git rerere`](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67#.d8f95i5j7)

**R**ecorded **R**eused **R**esolution

```
# enabled the option to record the 
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

By the way, if you prefer rerere to auto-stage files it solved (I do), you can ask it to: you just need to tweak your configuration like so:

```
git config --global rerere.autoupdate true
```

[image]